# Folium HeatMap isn't coloring correctly

Tags: heatmap, folium

I have a bunch of points the US and I want to see a heatmap. The problem is the precision of the points is "too good", so everything has an amount of 1.0 and no two points are actually equal. 95% of my points are in Portland, but the map doesn't show that at all.

[image: See current image here]

What parameters in HeatMap do I need to change so Portland would be so much more red/dark/whatever than the other cities?

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:  map_data = pd.read_csv(file)
    map_data = map_data[['Latitude','Longitude']].astype('float').dropna()

    hmap = folium.Map(location=startingLocation, zoom_start=5)

    hm_wide = HeatMap( list(zip(map_data.Latitude.values, 
                                map_data.Longitude.values)),
                    min_opacity=0.02,
                    radius=1, 
                    blur=1,
                    max_zoom=5)

    hmap.add_child(hm_wide)
    hmap.save(os.path.join('.', 'heatmap.html'))
```

And my data looks like this:

```
    Latitude,Longitude
    36.20687609941977,-115.24184692135688
    45.71099938280254,-122.62603536120108
    45.57399590606743,-122.59763015879912
    47.822566746145846,-122.3430923114917
    49.24992508600481,-123.11913651236131
```

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Comment: Without the file containing the coordinates your code is not reproducible. Anyway, I do not see any problem in it. If you want to give a visual representation of your data at a country level, maybe a choropleth map is more suitable for the purpose.